# M/S concerns regarding the end-user

Tags: ms, recording

I know the question of M/S vs. X/Y recordings has been discussed many times as well as the benefits of both. All of that aside, I'm a little concerned about how my M/S recordings will be used by the end-users. What are your thoughts as far as being decoded incorrectly or phase issues go?

Comment: Are you doing LtRt mixes of a 5.1 mix? If so then keep an eye on your phase scope. It could be decoded by a dolby decoder incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I may be in the minority here, but most of the time when I come across an M/S recording in my library that I want to use, I usually do a quick M/S to stereo conversion using a plugin preset (S1 Imager, Bx _control, etc) and move on. It's rare that I'll actually take the time to experiment with the width of the stereo image. That being said, I appreciate the format but don't normally take full advantage of it, for the sake of time and productivity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jay. I'm with you as far as the way I use M/S effects. I recently put up an online library and I'm debating on how to record my newest set of effects. I just wanted to get a sense of how many mixers and sound designers take the time to use M/S to it's full potential. I would hate to see it get used improperly. Thanks again for your input.